# Menu Module to look like DNA

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I'm looking for a menu module that looks similar to: http://tarponinvest.com.br/ (the DNA structured top menu).

[image]

Searching for it in the JED wasn't fruitful, since this is rather specific. (The multitude of extensions was on graphical changes to the menu or dropdown boxes, etc.)

Comment: Not really apropiate for SO but checkout and support the Joomla Proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/

Answer (score 1):

The menu looks like something created by MacroMedia Dreamweaver. If there is not already a module on JED (http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems), then your left to create your own module for this.
Read here about how to create a module: http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_simple_module

Comment: Yes I came to the same conclusion, there's really not enough time (and it's not worth it) to make the module myself, so I hoped there would already be one.

Comment: Creating a custom module isn't really hard to do. If you have access to the existing code, it should be possible to create a module from it. But of course it needs some time :)